# Trouble validating a Facebook token

Tags: cocoa, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm building a small Facebook login library for OS X. This isn't because there are no SDKs out there, but because I'd like something native to Cocoa that can encapsulate the login process. I'v successfully requested an access token from the Facebook login URL. I use this string format to perform the login:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token
```

For the `redirect_uri` field I pass `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` as per the Facebook documentation. I take whatever that response is and parse the URL. I'll either get a token or a failure. The token seems to come back okay. The trouble is in the next step.

Immediately after receiving my token, I attempt to validate it. I use the "debug" endpoint, like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=%@&access_token=%@
```

I pass my new token as the `input_token` and this is where it gets sticky. I've tried passing my client token, but that causes the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid OAuth access token. error 190.)`

If I pass my `app ID | app secret`, I get a different error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. ((#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app error 100.)

I'm not sure what's happening here, or what to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, did you solved the problem? I also meet the #100 OAuth error when I pass my `app ID | app secret`.

Comment: The real answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37522695/7149454

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) API is for if you want to do things *as* the app, not as the user. Once a user has logged in, all you need is their access token to get info about them, read their info, publish things (all of course assuming you have an access token with permissions to do what you're trying to do). So in your case, now that you have an access token, go ahead and try getting info about the user using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@
```

and you'll get back something like this:

```
{
   "id": "542440888",
   "name": "Max Rabin",
   "first_name": "Max",
   "last_name": "Rabin",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/MY_USER_NAME",
   "username": "MY_USER_NAME",
   "birthday": "11/22/YEAR",
   "hometown": {
      "id": "110970792260960",
      "name": "Los Angeles, California"
   },
   "location": {
      "id": "110970792260960",
      "name": "Los Angeles, California"
   },
   "bio": "There are 10 kinds of people in this world.\r\n01: Those who know trinary\r\n02: Those who don't\r\n10: Those who confuse it with binary",
   "gender": "male",
   "email": "MY_EMAIL",
   "timezone": 2,
   "locale": "en_US",
   "languages": [
      {
         "id": "106059522759137",
         "name": "English"
      }
   ],
   "verified": true,
   "updated_time": "2013-10-21T10:02:49+0000"
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a little security hazard? Someone can have a user access token from other app and then he can send it to our server and get logged in as other user. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Facebook client tokens are scoped to the app. They won't work in another app.

Comment: Thx for clarifying this. In other words, if i want to check the scope of any token, i have to make a request and check if it is denied or not ? ( I'm trying to catch the case where a user reduce the default scope i chose, and prevent my app to crash )

Comment: @AugustoSamaméBarrientos That's wrong. User access tokens are not scoped to an app. Using for example the /me route requires only a user access token, and not any app related information.

Comment: @sermonionx you're mixing up concepts. When you let your users signup to use your app, you as the app developer, will get a client user token from Facebook. It uniquely identifies the user and the permissions he gave when signing up to the app. It's scope though is only your app. It cannot be used in others. It will let you get back data on the /me route, because it's scoped to the user, but for app-related permissions, it's scoped to your app only.