# The Facebook login doesn't work anymore since I upgraded the Firebase app to the new Console (only)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

I had a working app with Facebook & Email Login feature, since I upgrade the Firebase console (only, the sdk has not been update).

The app release before the Firebase 3.0 was working before, but it is not anymore able to sign/log with Facebook after the console has been upgraded.

**What I have done:**

1 - Upgraded the Firebase console

*Because of Firebase & Facebook console update, I also had to put the Oauth Callback to the Facebook App*

2 - Pasted the Firebase Facebook OAuth Callback to the Facebook console (before it was void)  `https://xxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler``

**The Exception:**

The firebase Auth listener trigger a Firebase Error :

> Invalid authentication credentials provided. and Facebook :
>   {"providerErrorInfo":{"code":400,"message":"Unsuccessful debug_token
>   response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) You must
>   provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or
>   developer of the
>   app\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"DG4lLRJHFBS\"}}"}}

**The FirebaseError Code:**

In the decompiled code of the FirebaseAndroidSdk, the error object is:

> 0 = {java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@22680} "code" ->
>   "INVALID_CREDENTIALS"
>
> 1 = {java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@22681}
>   "message" -> "Invalid authentication credentials provided."
>
> 2 = {java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@22682} "details" ->
>   "{"providerErrorInfo":{"code":400,"message":"Unsuccessful debug_token
>   response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) You must
>   provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or
>   developer of the app\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"BtB3JF2qmku\"}}"}}"

with the decompiled code:

```
private void makeAuthenticationRequest(String urlPath, Map<String, String> params, AuthResultHandler handler) {
    final AuthenticationManager.AuthAttempt attempt = this.newAuthAttempt(handler);
    this.makeRequest(urlPath, HttpRequestType.GET, params, Collections.emptyMap(), new RequestHandler() {
        public void onResult(Map<String, Object> result) {
            Object errorResponse = result.get("error");
            String token = (String)Utilities.getOrNull(result, "token", String.class);
            if(errorResponse == null && token != null) {
                if(!AuthenticationManager.this.attemptHasBeenPreempted(attempt)) {
                    AuthenticationManager.this.authWithCredential(token, result, attempt);
                }
            } else {
                FirebaseError error = AuthenticationManager.this.decodeErrorResponse(errorResponse);
                AuthenticationManager.this.fireAuthErrorIfNotPreempted(error, attempt);
            }

        }

        public void onError(IOException e) {
            FirebaseError error = new FirebaseError(-24, "There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            AuthenticationManager.this.fireAuthErrorIfNotPreempted(error, attempt);
        }
    });
}
```

At AuthListener level, the firebaseError code : `-20`

https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/FirebaseError.html

> The specified authentication credentials are invalid.

**The Facebook Error Code:**

code `400`

Nothing relevant found here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors

**The code for Authing:**

```
    public void authWithFirebase(final String provider, Map<String, String> options) {
        if (options.containsKey(AUTH_OPTIONS_ERROR)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageToDisplayEvent(options.get(AUTH_OPTIONS_ERROR), true));
        } else {
            if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTH_PROVIDER_TWITTER)) {
                // if the provider is twitter, we must pass in additional options, so use the options endpoint
                ref.authWithOAuthToken(provider, options, new AuthResultHandler(provider));
            } else {
                // if the provider is not twitter, we just need to pass in the oauth_token
                ref.authWithOAuthToken(provider, options.get(AUTH_OPTIONS_TOKEN), new AuthResultHandler(provider));
            }
        }
    }
```

**TOKEN Validity:**

From the code above, the Token is confirmed valid since :

https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=%7Byour_access_token%7D return a valid JSON

And the Facebook Tool AccessToken https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken return a still valid TOKEN

**What changed from user point of view:**

Now, When I click on the FacebookLoginButton, I have a new dialog that ask "connection as %FacebookUserName", with 2 buttons ("Unconnect" & "Cancel")

I posted a bug report at Firebase, but I even do not know if this is Facebook or Firebase, any help, advise for exploring new issue surface or solution is welcome.

Comment: Well, since I upgraded to Firebase 3.0 I have the same issue with Google Sign In. I haven't upgraded my SDK but the console and now I can't authorize with the token. I get `Invalid authentication credentials provided` error. Therefore it seems to be a Firebase issue.

Comment: @Durian happy to hear you, with such complex auth process, you are never 100% sure that the issue is not by your side. A bug is open for me, please add one for you to increase the awareness of Firebase team (yesterday, one told me I was alone from what he heard) https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Hey! Sounds like you're running into trouble. Can you reach out to me at rob@firebase.com?

Comment: @Durian If you're running into any issues, please reach out to me as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Firebase 3.0 when I use the facebook test app keys. I can log in if I use my facebook production app keys, then I think this is a OAuth bug between Firebase and Facebook test apps.

Comment: @Ch4vi did you try my solution below ?

Comment: @Anthony I did, but I had these option switched off by default, I checked in both apps(test and production) but I only have the problem in with the test application in facebook. I think is a Firebase bug because my configurations are the same and I changed the keys and everything in my Firebase console.

Comment: @Ch4vi, I just have the app in Prod. But I get another issue when I use a Facebook test user. Do you get the same error message ?

Comment: @Anthony yes, I'm having `Facebook sign in failed error: An internal error has occured. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app"` Do you have your facebook app active and public?(the green dot besides your app name in facebook) It's the only difference between my pro and test apps

Comment: @Ch4vi yes the app is active and public (sorry for being late, I though I already answered). Did you went forward with this tricky issue ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Facebook Developper Console, switch-off the option about the "app key that is integrated in the client".

For me this changed the behavior. I will give more information as far I get from Firebase/Facebook

Here is a screenshot to help you setting up Facebook:

[image]

Comment: @Anthony - Can you print a screen shot to show were this option is in the Facebook Developer Console??? I've had a look around and can't find it. I'm currently having the same issues :(  Thanks

Comment: @Dave0504 Screenshot added. Do not forget to Inc the answer if this is ok for you.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for your help Anthony, however I'm still having the same issue, and now think it is a Firebase problem, rather than Facebook. +1 for the help though :)

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, everything seems to be correct but I always get this error, when logging in with a test user (a Facebook account added under the Tester Role in FB Dev console). For the screenshot above, I remember seeing it when I created the app in Facebook, but I can't find it again - I suspect it's a one time setup?

Comment: Found it, under Settings->Advanced, and that solved this for me too thankfully :)