# Check an User token with Facebook API with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a web app, where user are signing with facebook, then I save their access token in my database. I'm trying to check if their token are valid with the PHP SDK then if the token  is valid , I'd like to extend it.
The problem is that I get an error message which tells me:

> (#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app

Does that mean only app dev team member's can have their token extended or verified?

Here is my code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
    'my_client_id',
    'my_client_secret'
);

$session = new FacebookSession($user_token);

try {
    $resp = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/debug_token', array(
            'input_token' => $user_token
        )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

  //profile ok
} catch(\Exception $exp) {
   //profile ko 
}
```

Comment: Are the client id and secret you provided in setDefaultApplication the correct IDs for your app, as set up by the dev team?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble validating a Facebook token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688494/trouble-validating-a-facebook-token)

Comment: `new FacebookSession($user_token);` - here's your mistake. You need to initiate a session with the _app_ token, so that this will be used as the access_token parameter in the API call. (Or you should also be able to pass that parameter explicitly within the parameter array, that should take preference over the token stored in the session.)

Comment: Thanks to CBroe ! you were right, in deed I just needed to pass to new FacebookSession('app_id' . '|' . 'app_secret');

Answer (score 0):

The [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) API is for if you want to do things as the app, not as the user.

Comment: How would you debug a normal user auth token? Like to see if it's expired.